# Angular 5 component global variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

My question is Global variable is `undefined` when the `ngOnIt` , `AfterViewInit` method is called.
I'm fetching data from json file which is in asset folder. I have successfully passed the data to `gotodef()` function with one parameter. And from that `gotodef()` function I'm returning the variable.
What I need is I want to return the array which is in gotodef() function with satisfying the condition from the json file (I mean from subscribe method).

Following is my code,

```
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {

 column_data : any;

 constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {
            this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/world_bank.json')
             .subscribe(data => {
                      data = (<any>data)._body;
                      let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(data);
                      let outage_columns = obj.Outage.Columns;
                      let default_columns = obj.Default.Columns; // default_column's value is 2 in this case.
                      if(outage_columns == '')
                      {
                          let column_data = default_columns;
                          this.gotodef(column_data);
                      }

              });
    }
}
```

Gotodef Function :-

```
gotodef(column_data:any)
{

    if(column_data === '2')
    {
        console.log('in if statement');

        let columndata_1 = [
                { text: 'Product Name 1',  datafield: 'ProductName', width: '20%' , hidden:true },
                { text: 'Quantity per Unit',  datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right' , width: '20%'},
                { text: 'Unit Price',  datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: this.cellsrenderer, width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued', align: 'center' , width: '20%'}
            ];
        return columndata_1;
    }
}
```

Now, It's jqwidgets component's line **I want use the return value from function here in this.column_data** but I can return it's value but first time it's undefined.

```
columns: any[] = this.gotodef(this.column_data);
```

So, I'm confuse how to achieve this task. How to declare proper variable to do this task.

**EDIT :-**

Full code (With Jqwidgets code)

```
@ViewChild('myGrid') myGrid: jqxGridComponent;

Rowclick(event: any): void {
    var args = event.args;
    var selectedRowIndex = args.rowindex;
    // alert(selectedRowIndex);
    $('#right_panel').css('display','block');
    $('body').removeClass('aside-menu-hidden');
}
source: any =
{
    datatype: 'xml',
    datafields: [
        { name: 'ProductName', type: 'string'  },
        { name: 'QuantityPerUnit', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'UnitPrice', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'UnitsInStock', type: 'float' },
        { name: 'Discontinued', type: 'bool' }
    ],
    root: 'Products',
    record: 'Product',
    id: 'ProductID',
    url: '../../assets/product.xml'
};

dataAdapter: any = new jqx.dataAdapter(this.source);

cellsrenderer = (row: number, columnfield: string, value: string | number, defaulthtml: string, columnproperties: any, rowdata: any): string => {
    if (value < 20) {
        return `<span style='margin: 4px; float:${columnproperties.cellsalign}; color: #ff0000;'>${value}</span>`;
    }
    else {
        return `<span style='margin: 4px; float:${columnproperties.cellsalign}; color: #008000;'>${value}</span>`;
    }
};

gotodef(column_data:any)
{
    console.log(column_data);
    if(column_data === '1')
    {
        console.log('in if');
        let columndata_1 = [
                { text: 'Product Name 1',  datafield: 'ProductName', width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Quantity per Unit',  datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right' , width: '20%'},
                { text: 'Unit Price',  datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: this.cellsrenderer, width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued', align: 'center' , width: '20%'}
            ];
        return columndata_1;
    }
    if(column_data === '2')
    {
        console.log('in second if');
        let columndata_1 = [
                { text: 'Product Name 1',  datafield: 'ProductName', width: '20%' , hidden:true },
                { text: 'Quantity per Unit',  datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right' , width: '20%'},
                { text: 'Unit Price',  datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: this.cellsrenderer, width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued', align: 'center' , width: '20%'}
            ];


    }
}

columns: any[] = this.gotodef(this.column_data);

columngroups: any[] =
[
    { text: 'Product Details', align: 'center', name: 'ProductDetails' }
];
```

If I put condition like this it's working,

```
if(column_data === '2' || typeof column_data === 'undefined')
    {
        console.log('in second if');
        let columndata_1 = [
                { text: 'Product Name 1',  datafield: 'ProductName', width: '20%' , hidden:true },
                { text: 'Quantity per Unit',  datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right' , width: '20%'},
                { text: 'Unit Price',  datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: this.cellsrenderer, width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued', align: 'center' , width: '20%'}
            ];


    }
```

So, from this check I have figure it out that first time it's undefined and then it's setting value.

**EDIT-2** :-

Thank you @ChrisG.
My question is confusing so I have tried to explain it.

What I need is I want to return the array which is in gotodef() function with satisfying the condition from the json file (I mean from subscribe method).

Jqwidget's code and `gotodef()` function is in same class. 
So, I can get json file's data from function's argument-1 like this, `gotodef(argument-1)` in subscriber method and I can pass it to `gotodef()`.

So, I can get `column_data` from function and column_data's value is '2' it may be 1,2 or 3 etc.

Now if column_data has 2 value then I have to change the array.  Please see the below code.

```
if(column_data === '2')
    {
        console.log('in second if');
        let Column_data_which_I_havetoreturn = [
                { text: 'Product Name 1',  datafield: 'ProductName', width: '20%' , hidden:true },
                { text: 'Quantity per Unit',  datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right' , width: '20%'},
                { text: 'Unit Price',  datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: this.cellsrenderer, width: '20%' },
                { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued', align: 'center' , width: '20%'}
            ];

     return Column_data_which_I_havetoreturn;
    }
```

and Now I have to use this returned data to this syntax,

```
columns: any[] = this.gotodef(Column_data_which_I_havetoreturn);
```

So, For that I have declared the variable `Column_data_which_I_havetoreturn` aboe the class like this `Column_data_which_I_havetoreturn : any`. I'm getting Column_data_which_I_havetoreturn but it's first time undefined.

Comment: how are you setting ``this.column_data`` ?

Comment: My guess is you need `this.column_data = this.gotodef(default_columns);` However your code is incomplete, and I have trouble understanding what the actual question is here. If you're getting an error, show the error verbatim and mention the line  that's causing it.

Comment: @CruelEngine. Actually the problem is I'm not able correctly set it's value because I'm returning the value from `gotodef()` function and I have to set this return value here in `columns: any[] = this.gotodef(this.column_data);` this line.

Comment: @WebRence But where is `columns:` ? I'm not seeing it in either of the snippets. Are you confusing it with `column_data`?

Comment: @ChrisG. Thank you for your reply but where I have to put this code in subscibe method ?

Comment: @ChrisG. I'm editing my question. It's a jqwidget's by default array. Please check I have edited my question with full code snipet.

Comment: all you have to do is ``this.column_data = this.gotodef(column_data)`` inside the subscription

Comment: @CruelEngine That's what I already mentioned, however it seems to be `this.columns = this.gotodef(default_columns);`

Comment: i think his ``columns : [] = this.gotodef(default_columns) `` initialization is not working , and he has to do it inside the subscription

Comment: @CruelEngine. Thank you for your time but I have tried with it but it's not working. I don't know why.  Because I have return the data which I got in `gotodef()` function.

Comment: @ChrisG Because what I need is I want to return the array which is in `gotodef()` function with satisfying the condition from the json file (I mean from subscribe method).

Comment: @WebRence Yes, I'm aware. You basically want this: https://jsfiddle.net/quys7ft2/ (still not sure what the actual issue is)

Comment: @ChrisG. Oh got you man. Thank you Let me try with your jsfiddle. I'll Let you know in 20 minutes.

Comment: @ChrisG. Thank you so much for your time and efforts. You made a object outside the class. so, this is not gonna work. I have edited my question with EDIT-2 because my question was confusing please check it.

Comment: I'm well aware of what you're trying to do, but it simply cannot work as you expect it to work. Also note that all the relevant code from the fiddle takes places *inside* the class. The fact that I instantiated the class to log the result doesn't matter (and the same thing happens in your framework anyway).

Comment: Also note that you need to choose better variable and function names. This for example: `column_data === '2'` suggests that `column_data` is just a number, but the name sounds like it contains data. And the array you're returning from the weirdly named `gotodef` doesn't contain data either but column definitions. Here's a new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3uuroam/ (`columns` receives initial data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution (I changed a few names):

```js
class DashboardComponent {

  columnDataIndex = 1  // initial value

  constructor() {
    this.columns = this.getColumnData(this.columnDataIndex)  // initialize this.columns
    // ajax call here
    // in subscribe, do:
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("ajax call succeeded");
      this.columnDataIndex = 2
      this.columns = this.getColumnData(this.columnDataIndex)
    }, 500);
  }
  
  getColumnData(index) {
    var column_data = [
      { text: 'Product Name 1',  datafield: 'ProductName', width: '20%' },
      { text: 'Quantity per Unit',  datafield: 'QuantityPerUnit', cellsalign: 'right', align: 'right' , width: '20%'},
      { text: 'Unit Price',  datafield: 'UnitPrice', align: 'right', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2', width: '20%' },
      { text: 'Units In Stock', datafield: 'UnitsInStock', cellsalign: 'right', cellsrenderer: this.cellsrenderer, width: '20%' },
      { text: 'Discontinued', columntype: 'checkbox', datafield: 'Discontinued', align: 'center' , width: '20%'}
    ];
    if (index == 2) column_data[0].hidden = "true";
    return column_data;
  }
  
  columns : any

}

const DC = new DashboardComponent();
console.log("columns", DC.columns[0]);
setTimeout(() => {
 console.log("columns", DC.columns[0]);
 }, 1000);
```

The fields should speak for themselves, but the basic idea is that the AJAX call so far only changes the type of column data that's supposed to ultimately end up in `.columns`, so I added an initial value `1`, initialize `.columns` in the constructor, then update it after a successful (simulated) AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you chris. Literally you have spent a lot of time for this question. It means a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way

```
this.gotodef(this.column_data);
```